# How can I filter a JSON data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a huge JSON data as below. Now I need to filter and get all the attributes of json data pertaining to the month entered.

My JSON data is :

```
"maindata" :[
   {
      "month":"multi",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Pike Place Roast Brewed Coffee Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Starbucks VIA Ready Brew French Roast",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":548,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   },
   {
      "month":"multi",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Starbucks Caffé Verona Blend, Whole Bean",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"asia-pacific",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":20,
      "name":"Starbucks Caffè Verona K-Cup Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":3,
      "roast":"dark",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Milk Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":233,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   },
   {
      "month":"multi",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":50,
      "name":"Starbucks VIA Ready Brew Decaf Italian Roast",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":5,
      "roast":"medium",
      "type":"regular"
   },
   {
      "month":"august",
      "category":"coffee",
      "price":40,
      "name":"Guatemala Antigua Espresso Verismo Pods",
      "flavor":"flavored",
      "count":587,
      "roast":"blonde",
      "type":"decaffinated"
   }
]
```

Can anyone help me how can I get this working ?
I have tried to use JSONParse method but that alone doesnt suffice the purpose.

Comment: Shouldn't be to hard, what parts are you getting stuck on? Nit picks: That's not a JSON object, but maybe a key out of one, `asia-pacific` is not a month on the year.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, Ignore the asia-pacific as of now .

Comment: What have you tried so far? It could be really simple, just iterate the object and compare the `month` property of each element.

Comment: or use `whatever.maindata.map()` to extract an array of the "month" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try filtering your data set.

Here, the filter matches the input value of 'multi';

you can change it to some other value (or even make it dynamic based on user input)

```js
// sample data
var data = {
  "maindata": [{
    "month": "multi",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 50,
    "name": "Pike Place Roast Brewed Coffee Verismo Pods",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 5,
    "roast": "medium",
    "type": "regular"
  }, {
    "month": "august",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 40,
    "name": "Starbucks VIA Ready Brew French Roast",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 548,
    "roast": "blonde",
    "type": "decaffinated"
  }, {
    "month": "multi",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 50,
    "name": "Starbucks Caffé Verona Blend, Whole Bean",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 5,
    "roast": "medium",
    "type": "regular"
  }, {
    "month": "asia-pacific",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 20,
    "name": "Starbucks Caffè Verona K-Cup Pods",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 3,
    "roast": "dark",
    "type": "regular"
  }, {
    "month": "august",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 40,
    "name": "Milk Verismo Pods",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 233,
    "roast": "blonde",
    "type": "decaffinated"
  }, {
    "month": "multi",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 50,
    "name": "Starbucks VIA Ready Brew Decaf Italian Roast",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 5,
    "roast": "medium",
    "type": "regular"
  }, {
    "month": "august",
    "category": "coffee",
    "price": 40,
    "name": "Guatemala Antigua Espresso Verismo Pods",
    "flavor": "flavored",
    "count": 587,
    "roast": "blonde",
    "type": "decaffinated"
  }]
};

// hard-coded - can be set to a dynamic value if need be
var inputMonth = 'multi';

var months = data.maindata.filter(function(elem) {
  if (elem.month === inputMonth) {
    return elem;
  }
});

var results = {};
results['data'] = months;

document.getElementById('myresults').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

```html
<pre id='myresults'>
</pre>
```